# Chainlink VRF V2 - TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1

Tags: chainlink, uint256, vrf, chainlink-vrf

**I tried to use Chainlink VRF V2 on my contract but got errors like shown picture below. Does anyone know how to solve this?**

> My Chainlink VRFV2 Oracle function

```
/// @dev chainlink oracle function to generate random number; used for Battle Card Attack and Defense Strength

    function _createRandomNum(address _sender)
        external
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        //require(s_results[_sender] == 0, "Already requested");
        requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, //gasLane
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        s_players[requestId] = _sender;
        s_results[_sender] = MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, _sender);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords)
        internal
        override
    {
        uint256 randomValue = (randomWords[0] % 10) + 1;
        s_results[s_players[requestId]] = randomValue;
        if (randomValue == 0) {
            randomValue = randomWords[0] / 2;
        }
        emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, randomValue);
    }
```

> getRandomValue function or Getting the result of VRF number

```
function getRandomValue(address player) public returns (uint256) {
        return s_randomValue = s_results[player];
```

> My Full Smart-Contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";

/// @title BattleCard
/// @notice This contract handles the token management and battle logic for the BattleCard game
/// @notice Version 1.0.0
/// @author Dewangga Praxindo

contract BattleCard is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Supply, VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    string public baseURI; // baseURI where token metadata is stored
    uint256 public totalSupply; // Total number of tokens minted
    uint256 public constant DEVIL = 0;
    uint256 public constant GRIFFIN = 1;
    uint256 public constant FIREBIRD = 2;
    uint256 public constant KAMO = 3;
    uint256 public constant KUKULKAN = 4;
    uint256 public constant CELESTION = 5;

    /* State variables */
    // Chainlink VRF Variables
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    uint256 public constant MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH = 10;

    enum BattleStatus {
        PENDING,
        STARTED,
        ENDED
    }

    /// @dev GameToken struct to store player token info
    struct GameToken {
        string name; /// @param name battle card name; set by player
        uint256 id; /// @param id battle card token id; will be randomly generated
        uint256 attackStrength; /// @param attackStrength battle card attack; generated randomly
        uint256 defenseStrength; /// @param defenseStrength battle card defense; generated randomly
    }

    /// @dev Player struct to store player info
    struct Player {
        address playerAddress; /// @param playerAddress player wallet address
        string playerName; /// @param playerName player name; set by player during registration
        uint256 playerMana; /// @param playerMana player mana; affected by battle results
        uint256 playerHealth; /// @param playerHealth player health; affected by battle results
        bool inBattle; /// @param inBattle boolean to indicate if a player is in battle
    }

    /// @dev Battle struct to store battle info
    struct Battle {
        BattleStatus battleStatus; /// @param battleStatus enum to indicate battle status
        bytes32 battleHash; /// @param battleHash a hash of the battle name
        string name; /// @param name battle name; set by player who creates battle
        address[2] players; /// @param players address array representing players in this battle
        uint8[2] moves; /// @param moves uint array representing players' move
        address winner; /// @param winner winner address
    }

    mapping(address => uint256) public playerInfo; // Mapping of player addresses to player index in the players array
    mapping(address => uint256) public playerTokenInfo; // Mapping of player addresses to player token index in the gameTokens array
    mapping(string => uint256) public battleInfo; // Mapping of battle name to battle index in the battles array

    // map rollers to requestIds
    mapping(uint256 => address) private s_players;
    // map vrf results to rollers
    mapping(address => uint256) public s_results;

    Player[] public players; // Array of players
    GameToken[] public gameTokens; // Array of game tokens
    Battle[] public battles; // Array of battles

    function isPlayer(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
        if (playerInfo[addr] == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getPlayer(address addr) public view returns (Player memory) {
        require(isPlayer(addr), "Player doesn't exist!");
        return players[playerInfo[addr]];
    }

    function getAllPlayers() public view returns (Player[] memory) {
        return players;
    }

    function isPlayerToken(address addr) public view returns (bool) {
        if (playerTokenInfo[addr] == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getPlayerToken(address addr)
        public
        view
        returns (GameToken memory)
    {
        require(isPlayerToken(addr), "Game token doesn't exist!");
        return gameTokens[playerTokenInfo[addr]];
    }

    function getAllPlayerTokens() public view returns (GameToken[] memory) {
        return gameTokens;
    }

    // Battle getter function
    function isBattle(string memory _name) public view returns (bool) {
        if (battleInfo[_name] == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getBattle(string memory _name)
        public
        view
        returns (Battle memory)
    {
        require(isBattle(_name), "Battle doesn't exist!");
        return battles[battleInfo[_name]];
    }

    function getAllBattles() public view returns (Battle[] memory) {
        return battles;
    }

    function updateBattle(string memory _name, Battle memory _newBattle)
        private
    {
        require(isBattle(_name), "Battle doesn't exist");
        battles[battleInfo[_name]] = _newBattle;
    }

    // Events
    event NewPlayer(address indexed owner, string name);
    event NewBattle(
        string battleName,
        address indexed player1,
        address indexed player2
    );
    event BattleEnded(
        string battleName,
        address indexed winner,
        address indexed loser
    );
    event BattleMove(string indexed battleName, bool indexed isFirstMove);
    event NewGameToken(
        address indexed owner,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 attackStrength,
        uint256 defenseStrength
    );
    event RoundEnded(address[2] damagedPlayers);

    event RequestSent(uint256 indexed requestId, address indexed _sender);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 indexed requestId, uint256 indexed result);

    /// @dev Initializes the contract by setting a `metadataURI` to the token collection
    /// @param _metadataURI baseURI where token metadata is stored
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        string memory _metadataURI,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit
    ) ERC1155(_metadataURI) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        baseURI = _metadataURI; // Set baseURI
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        initialize();
    }

    function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyOwner {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

    function initialize() private {
        gameTokens.push(GameToken("", 0, 0, 0));
        players.push(Player(address(0), "", 0, 0, false));
        battles.push(
            Battle(
                BattleStatus.PENDING,
                bytes32(0),
                "",
                [address(0), address(0)],
                [0, 0],
                address(0)
            )
        );
    }

    /// @dev Registers a player
    /// @param _name player name; set by player
    function registerPlayer(string memory _name, string memory _gameTokenName)
        external
    {
        require(!isPlayer(msg.sender), "Player already registered"); // Require that player is not already registered

        uint256 _id = players.length;
        players.push(Player(msg.sender, _name, 10, 25, false)); // Adds player to players array
        playerInfo[msg.sender] = _id; // Creates player info mapping

        createRandomGameToken(_gameTokenName);

        emit NewPlayer(msg.sender, _name); // Emits NewPlayer event
    }

    /// @dev internal function to generate random number; used for Battle Card Attack and Defense Strength
    // function _createRandomNum(uint256 _max, address _sender)
    //     internal
    //     view
    //     returns (uint256 randomValue)
    // {
    //     uint256 randomNum = uint256(
    //         keccak256(
    //             abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, _sender)
    //         )
    //     );

    //     randomValue = randomNum % _max;
    //     if (randomValue == 0) {
    //         randomValue = _max / 2;
    //     }

    //     return randomValue;
    // }

    /// @dev chainlink oracle function to generate random number; used for Battle Card Attack and Defense Strength
    function _createRandomNum(address _sender)
        external
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        //require(s_results[_sender] == 0, "Already requested");
        requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, //gasLane
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        s_players[requestId] = _sender;
        s_results[_sender] = MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, _sender);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords)
        internal
        override
    {
        uint256 randomValue = (randomWords[0] % 10) + 1;
        s_results[s_players[requestId]] = randomValue;
        if (randomValue == 0) {
            randomValue = randomWords[0] / 2;
        }
        emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, randomValue);
    }

    /// @dev internal function to create a new Battle Card
    function _createGameToken(string memory _name)
        internal
        returns (GameToken memory)
    {
        uint256 randAttackStrength = getRandomValue(
            MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH,
            msg.sender
        );
        uint256 randDefenseStrength = MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH -
            randAttackStrength;

        uint8 randId = uint8(
            uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))) %
                100
        );
        randId = randId % 6;
        if (randId == 0) {
            randId++;
        }

        GameToken memory newGameToken = GameToken(
            _name,
            randId,
            randAttackStrength,
            randDefenseStrength
        );

        uint256 _id = gameTokens.length;
        gameTokens.push(newGameToken);
        playerTokenInfo[msg.sender] = _id;

        _mint(msg.sender, randId, 1, "0x0");
        totalSupply++;

        emit NewGameToken(
            msg.sender,
            randId,
            randAttackStrength,
            randDefenseStrength
        );
        return newGameToken;
    }

    /// @dev Creates a new game token
    /// @param _name game token name; set by player
    function createRandomGameToken(string memory _name) public {
        require(!getPlayer(msg.sender).inBattle, "Player is in a battle"); // Require that player is not already in a battle
        require(isPlayer(msg.sender), "Please Register Player First"); // Require that the player is registered

        _createGameToken(_name); // Creates game token
    }

    function getTotalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply;
    }

    /// @dev Creates a new battle
    /// @param _name battle name; set by player
    function createBattle(string memory _name)
        external
        returns (Battle memory)
    {
        require(isPlayer(msg.sender), "Please Register Player First"); // Require that the player is registered
        require(!isBattle(_name), "Battle already exists!"); // Require battle with same name should not exist

        bytes32 battleHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_name));

        Battle memory _battle = Battle(
            BattleStatus.PENDING, // Battle pending
            battleHash, // Battle hash
            _name, // Battle name
            [msg.sender, address(0)], // player addresses; player 2 empty until they joins battle
            [0, 0], // moves for each player
            address(0) // winner address; empty until battle ends
        );

        uint256 _id = battles.length;
        battleInfo[_name] = _id;
        battles.push(_battle);

        return _battle;
    }

    /// @dev Player joins battle
    /// @param _name battle name; name of battle player wants to join
    function joinBattle(string memory _name) external returns (Battle memory) {
        Battle memory _battle = getBattle(_name);

        require(
            _battle.battleStatus == BattleStatus.PENDING,
            "Battle already started!"
        ); // Require that battle has not started
        require(
            _battle.players[0] != msg.sender,
            "Only player two can join a battle"
        ); // Require that player 2 is joining the battle
        require(!getPlayer(msg.sender).inBattle, "Already in battle"); // Require that player is not already in a battle

        _battle.battleStatus = BattleStatus.STARTED;
        _battle.players[1] = msg.sender;
        updateBattle(_name, _battle);

        players[playerInfo[_battle.players[0]]].inBattle = true;
        players[playerInfo[_battle.players[1]]].inBattle = true;

        emit NewBattle(_battle.name, _battle.players[0], msg.sender); // Emits NewBattle event
        return _battle;
    }

    function getRandomValue(address player) public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_results[player];
    }

    // Read battle move info for player 1 and player 2
    function getBattleMoves(string memory _battleName)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256 P1Move, uint256 P2Move)
    {
        Battle memory _battle = getBattle(_battleName);

        P1Move = _battle.moves[0];
        P2Move = _battle.moves[1];

        return (P1Move, P2Move);
    }

    function _registerPlayerMove(
        uint256 _player,
        uint8 _choice,
        string memory _battleName
    ) internal {
        require(
            _choice == 1 || _choice == 2,
            "Choice should be either 1 or 2!"
        );
        require(
            _choice == 1 ? getPlayer(msg.sender).playerMana >= 3 : true,
            "Mana not sufficient for attacking!"
        );
        battles[battleInfo[_battleName]].moves[_player] = _choice;
    }

    // User chooses attack or defense move for battle card
    function attackOrDefendChoice(uint8 _choice, string memory _battleName)
        external
    {
        Battle memory _battle = getBattle(_battleName);

        require(
            _battle.battleStatus == BattleStatus.STARTED,
            "Battle not started. Please tell another player to join the battle"
        ); // Require that battle has started
        require(
            _battle.battleStatus != BattleStatus.ENDED,
            "Battle has already ended"
        ); // Require that battle has not ended
        require(
            msg.sender == _battle.players[0] ||
                msg.sender == _battle.players[1],
            "You are not in this battle"
        ); // Require that player is in the battle

        require(
            _battle.moves[_battle.players[0] == msg.sender ? 0 : 1] == 0,
            "You have already made a move!"
        );

        _registerPlayerMove(
            _battle.players[0] == msg.sender ? 0 : 1,
            _choice,
            _battleName
        );

        _battle = getBattle(_battleName);
        uint256 _movesLeft = 2 -
            (_battle.moves[0] == 0 ? 0 : 1) -
            (_battle.moves[1] == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        emit BattleMove(_battleName, _movesLeft == 1 ? true : false);

        if (_movesLeft == 0) {
            _awaitBattleResults(_battleName);
        }
    }

    // Awaits battle results
    function _awaitBattleResults(string memory _battleName) internal {
        Battle memory _battle = getBattle(_battleName);

        require(
            msg.sender == _battle.players[0] ||
                msg.sender == _battle.players[1],
            "Only players in this battle can make a move"
        );

        require(
            _battle.moves[0] != 0 && _battle.moves[1] != 0,
            "Players still need to make a move"
        );

        _resolveBattle(_battle);
    }

    struct P {
        uint256 index;
        uint256 move;
        uint256 health;
        uint256 attack;
        uint256 defense;
    }

    /// @dev Resolve battle function to determine winner and loser of battle
    /// @param _battle battle; battle to resolve
    function _resolveBattle(Battle memory _battle) internal {
        P memory p1 = P(
            playerInfo[_battle.players[0]],
            _battle.moves[0],
            getPlayer(_battle.players[0]).playerHealth,
            getPlayerToken(_battle.players[0]).attackStrength,
            getPlayerToken(_battle.players[0]).defenseStrength
        );

        P memory p2 = P(
            playerInfo[_battle.players[1]],
            _battle.moves[1],
            getPlayer(_battle.players[1]).playerHealth,
            getPlayerToken(_battle.players[1]).attackStrength,
            getPlayerToken(_battle.players[1]).defenseStrength
        );

        address[2] memory _damagedPlayers = [address(0), address(0)];

        if (p1.move == 1 && p2.move == 1) {
            if (p1.attack >= p2.health) {
                _endBattle(_battle.players[0], _battle);
            } else if (p2.attack >= p1.health) {
                _endBattle(_battle.players[1], _battle);
            } else {
                players[p1.index].playerHealth -= p2.attack;
                players[p2.index].playerHealth -= p1.attack;

                players[p1.index].playerMana -= 3;
                players[p2.index].playerMana -= 3;

                // Both player's health damaged
                _damagedPlayers = _battle.players;
            }
        } else if (p1.move == 1 && p2.move == 2) {
            uint256 PHAD = p2.health + p2.defense;
            if (p1.attack >= PHAD) {
                _endBattle(_battle.players[0], _battle);
            } else {
                uint256 healthAfterAttack;

                if (p2.defense > p1.attack) {
                    healthAfterAttack = p2.health;
                } else {
                    healthAfterAttack = PHAD - p1.attack;

                    // Player 2 health damaged
                    _damagedPlayers[0] = _battle.players[1];
                }

                players[p2.index].playerHealth = healthAfterAttack;

                players[p1.index].playerMana -= 3;
                players[p2.index].playerMana += 3;
            }
        } else if (p1.move == 2 && p2.move == 1) {
            uint256 PHAD = p1.health + p1.defense;
            if (p2.attack >= PHAD) {
                _endBattle(_battle.players[1], _battle);
            } else {
                uint256 healthAfterAttack;

                if (p1.defense > p2.attack) {
                    healthAfterAttack = p1.health;
                } else {
                    healthAfterAttack = PHAD - p2.attack;

                    // Player 1 health damaged
                    _damagedPlayers[0] = _battle.players[0];
                }

                players[p1.index].playerHealth = healthAfterAttack;

                players[p1.index].playerMana += 3;
                players[p2.index].playerMana -= 3;
            }
        } else if (p1.move == 2 && p2.move == 2) {
            players[p1.index].playerMana += 3;
            players[p2.index].playerMana += 3;
        }

        emit RoundEnded(_damagedPlayers);

        // Reset moves to 0
        _battle.moves[0] = 0;
        _battle.moves[1] = 0;
        updateBattle(_battle.name, _battle);

        // Reset random attack and defense strength
        uint256 _randomAttackStrengthPlayer1 = getRandomValue(
            MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH,
            _battle.players[0]
        );
        gameTokens[playerTokenInfo[_battle.players[0]]]
            .attackStrength = _randomAttackStrengthPlayer1;
        gameTokens[playerTokenInfo[_battle.players[0]]].defenseStrength =
            MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH -
            _randomAttackStrengthPlayer1;

        uint256 _randomAttackStrengthPlayer2 = getRandomValue(
            MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH,
            _battle.players[1]
        );
        gameTokens[playerTokenInfo[_battle.players[1]]]
            .attackStrength = _randomAttackStrengthPlayer2;
        gameTokens[playerTokenInfo[_battle.players[1]]].defenseStrength =
            MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH -
            _randomAttackStrengthPlayer2;
    }

    function quitBattle(string memory _battleName) public {
        Battle memory _battle = getBattle(_battleName);
        require(
            _battle.players[0] == msg.sender ||
                _battle.players[1] == msg.sender,
            "You are not in this battle!"
        );

        _battle.players[0] == msg.sender
            ? _endBattle(_battle.players[1], _battle)
            : _endBattle(_battle.players[0], _battle);
    }

    /// @dev internal function to end the battle
    /// @param battleEnder winner address
    /// @param _battle battle; taken from attackOrDefend function
    function _endBattle(address battleEnder, Battle memory _battle)
        internal
        returns (Battle memory)
    {
        require(
            _battle.battleStatus != BattleStatus.ENDED,
            "Battle already ended"
        ); // Require that battle has not ended

        _battle.battleStatus = BattleStatus.ENDED;
        _battle.winner = battleEnder;
        updateBattle(_battle.name, _battle);

        uint256 p1 = playerInfo[_battle.players[0]];
        uint256 p2 = playerInfo[_battle.players[1]];

        players[p1].inBattle = false;
        players[p1].playerHealth = 25;
        players[p1].playerMana = 10;

        players[p2].inBattle = false;
        players[p2].playerHealth = 25;
        players[p2].playerMana = 10;

        address _battleLoser = battleEnder == _battle.players[0]
            ? _battle.players[1]
            : _battle.players[0];

        emit BattleEnded(_battle.name, battleEnder, _battleLoser); // Emits BattleEnded event

        return _battle;
    }

    // Turns uint256 into string
    function uintToStr(uint256 _i)
        internal
        pure
        returns (string memory _uintAsString)
    {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 j = _i;
        uint256 len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint256 k = len;
        while (_i != 0) {
            k = k - 1;
            uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - (_i / 10) * 10));
            bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
            bstr[k] = b1;
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }

    // Token URI getter function
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return
            string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, "/", uintToStr(tokenId), ".json"));
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address operator,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256[] memory ids,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal override(ERC1155, ERC1155Supply) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```

> Got errors like this.

```
TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.
   --> contracts/BattleCard.sol:281:38:
    |
281 |         uint256 randAttackStrength = getRandomValue(
    |                                      ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.
   --> contracts/BattleCard.sol:583:48:
    |
583 |         uint256 _randomAttackStrengthPlayer1 = getRandomValue(
    |                                                ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.
   --> contracts/BattleCard.sol:593:48:
    |
593 |         uint256 _randomAttackStrengthPlayer2 = getRandomValue(
    |                                                ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

the function `fulfillRandomWords` is called by Chainlink VRF, when you call the `requestRandomWords`.

You yourself are calling the `fulfillRandomWords` with the `MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH` and `msg.sender` parameters.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to change `MAX_ATTACK_DEFEND_STRENGTH` to `10` (the max number of attacks & def strength), but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

adding uint256 data type before address

```
function getRandomValue(uint256, address) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return s_randomValue;
    }
```